# Is it possible to make VSCode remember its last used Virtual Desktops in Windows?

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-10, virtual-desktop, windows-virtual-desktop

I usually have multiple virtual desktops in my Windows 10 machine. When Visual Studio Code restarts (e.g. upgrade), it does not remember where each instance was. All of them open in the current virtual desktop.

There is a [lot of issues](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues?q=is%3Aissue+label%3Aworkbench-os-integration+virtual+is%3Aclosed) about it in its bug tracker, but they are all closed and none resolved. The best one that I've found is [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues?q=is%3Aissue+label%3Aworkbench-os-integration+virtual+is%3Aclosed) that says they need a feature in Electron. The Electron project has a [related issue](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/5362) (vote for it!).

Since all VSCode related issues are closed, I'd like to know if it is possible to make VSCode remember its virtual desktops location when it was closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te current answer is "no". It just will be possible when Electon fix [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues?q=is%3Aissue+label%3Aworkbench-os-integration+virtual+is%3Aclosed).

I'll update this answer when it is possible.

Comment: The provided link points to a search result, not a single issue. I think I tracked down the correct issue: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/37494

Answer (score 1):

There is a new issue for Electron where we can see the progress for this feature:

https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/37494